# "I should have let you known"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

I was working on a song, and my friend pointed out this lyric to me while I played it for her.

> "I should have let you known that I'm a runner"

My friend thinks it should be

> "I should have let you know that I'm a runner"

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which sounds right to you? "I should have let you see that" or "I should have let you seen that?" If you can figure that one out, you can solve the problem in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "I should have let you known that ..." would be grammatically correct, no matter what follows. Of course song lyrics often subordinate correct grammar to meter or rhyme, but here there is little or no change in meter or possible rhyme.  I would advise using "I should have let you know that..." unless there is some very good reason for doing otherwise.

The word "known" is used in "I should have known that...", which might be a source of confusion,  but it is not used in the "let you know" form.

Comment: I wish the downvoter would indicate the problem seen with this answer, so that I could perhaps improve it.

Comment: Any thoughts? The downvote has me stuck in limbo.

Comment: I still think my answer is a good one @Jacob Prince but obviously soemoen else thinks otherwise. But tht person whoever it may be, hasn't said what about my answer should be improved, or what a different answer would look like, nor has anyone else.